# Как реализовать механизм отображения информации о ходе выполнения скрипта Python?

Tags: python

Есть скрипт который обрабатывает файлы и выводит на экран информацию о текущем шаге. Более-менее логику отладил, теперь хочу реализовать механизм уровня отображения информации (уменьшить кол-во отображаемой информации). Не пойму как сделать. Сейчас в скрипте есть много мест с командой.

```
print(Fore.RED + "[" + fname + "]", end='')
```

Не делать же логическую проверку на уровень отображения для каждой такой строки, наверняка есть более умное решение. В Python я относительный новичок.

Comment: Используйте существующие модули для логирования, там есть свои механизмы разграничения (например, если уровень логирования выставлен в ERROR, то всякие предупреждения и информационные сообщения выводиться не будут).

Comment: в вопросе указано что я начинающий. Поэтому, если можно поделитесь -какие модули больше смогут подойти под описанную задачу ?

Comment: Например, стандартный logging (то что в ответе) или [loguru](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru) (с ним проще работать, на мой взгляд). Есть еще [structlog](https://github.com/hynek/structlog), но я с ним не работал.

Comment: Вообще неплохо бы посмотреть примеры, что вы выводите, тогда можно было бы что-то конкретное посоветовать. И что вы подразумеваете под уровнем (ошибка/предупреждение/информация/отладка, как в модулях логирования, или вообще что-то другое).

Comment: я привел пример, по скрипту таких строк с десяток на обработку 1 файла. Отображаю в одной строке тем или иным знаком выполняемую задачу (чтение, очистка папки, остановка приложений, обработка, запись итогового файла и т.п.). Теперь хочу сделать упрощенный вид- один элемент на все действия с 1 файлом.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger()
>>> logger.error("ошибка")
ERROR:root:ошибка
>>> logger.info("инфо")
>>> # на экране пусто
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.info("info")
INFO:root:info
```

и чтоб сделать `, end='')` или `, end='   \r')` надо очень сильно углубиться в библиотеку  https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: другими словами, на данном уровне знания языка совет бросить эту затею ?

Comment: не в коем случае.